# Join two tables in PowerQuery by a date range

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have these two tables in PowerBI, one that stores payments made by associates, and another that have those associates categories. I need to join those two tables to have the the category the payment refers to. The problem is that Associates can change category, and I need to know the category the user had in the date of payment. So I need to join these two tables by `AssociateNo`, and `PaymentDate`, in way I'll get for each `Payments` record a record in `Associations` where `PaymentDate` is between `Start` and `End`.

```
Payments
ID      AssociateNo    PaymentDate           Value
1       1001           01/oct/2020    100,00
2       1001           02/oct/2020    120,00
3       1001           02/oct/2020    150,00
4       1002           04/oct/2020    160,00
5       1003           05/oct/2020    150,00
6       1004           10/nov/2020    120,00

Associations

AssociateNo   Start        End          Category
1001          10/01/2020   11/01/2020   A
1001          11/01/2020   11/01/2020   A
1001          10/01/2020   11/01/2020   A
```

PS1: I need to do this in PowerQuery, since I'll have further steps that will need this data.
PS1: `Associations` table is in a mysql database which I have control, so I can create a view in there if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

On the Associations table, convert the two date columns to numbers by click selecting and using Transform ... Data Type ... Decimal Number

Then Add Columns ... Custom Column... with formula

```
= {[Start] .. [End]}
```

click the arrows at the top of the new column header and choose Expand to New Rows from the dropdown

Transform the two original date columns and the new column back to date format by click selecting and using Transform ... Data Type ... Date

Now you have every possible date between the Start and End Date. File ... Close and Load ... the data to save it

Go into the Payments table and do a Home ... Merge Queries ... from this table and the Associations table using type Left Outer, linking the AssociateNo together, and linking the PaymentDate to the new column we created.  Expand and extract the Category

Sample code for associations table

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"AssociateNo", Int64.Type}, {"Start", Int64.Type}, {"End", Int64.Type}, {"Category", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each {[Start] .. [End]}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Start", type date}, {"End", type date}, {"Custom", type date}})
in #"Changed Type1"
```

Sample code for Payments table

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"AssociateNo", "PaymentDate"},Associations,{"AssociateNo", "Custom"},"Associations",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Queries",{{"PaymentDate", type date}}),
#"Expanded Associations" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Changed Type", "Associations", {"Category"}, {"Category"})
in  #"Expanded Associations"
```